# How can I exclude/remove a CDI extension that is added through a 3rd party jar?

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld

As the title says, I want to exclude/remove a CDI extension at runtime that is added through a 3rd party jar? I tried several like ( but with no success) :

- AlterableContext destroy
- veto-ing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You can remove it from the classpath, but if it is bundled with a jar that contains other stuff you need, this may not be an option. You can [veto](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/apidocs/jakarta.cdi/jakarta/enterprise/inject/spi/processannotatedtype#veto()) [certain](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/apidocs/jakarta.cdi/jakarta/enterprise/inject/spi/processbeanattributes#veto()) [things it does](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/apidocs/jakarta.cdi/jakarta/enterprise/inject/spi/processobservermethod#veto()). If that is not working, then either the extension does not properly respect vetoes, or it is adding (definitionally non-vetoable) [synthetic beans](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/apidocs/jakarta.cdi/jakarta/enterprise/inject/spi/processsyntheticbean) (or the like).

(For completeness, an [`AlterableContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/apidocs/jakarta.cdi/jakarta/enterprise/context/spi/alterablecontext) has nothing to do with portable extensions.)

Comment: I thought that by using AlterableContext, I might succeed in removing some "ExtensionBean" types from the ApplicationContext, but I guess the context is immutable in this regard. At a deeper level I guess I had a similar interaction with you on a similar topic on the helidon slack channel, regarding deactivating messaging channels by modifying the Helidon-messaging cdi extension to use specific properties. Similar to what smallrye is providing https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.22.1/concepts/advanced-config/.

Comment: It sounds then like you have a more specific question in mind?

Comment: Well, yea at the base level, the concern was to disable messaging channel registration and connection which happens inside the MessagingCDIExtension inside helidon messaging, but since these things are 3rd party, I tried to look outward to find a way if possible to disable the extension entirely. I guess the end result that I wanted to achieve is to either have a property at the "mp.messaging" level or at the channel config level to disable, similar to "tracing.enable" property.

Comment: Have you considered filing an enhancement on the [Helidon Github project](https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/issues)?